# Whats wrong with the way I declare my variables, because I keep getting a syntax 1064?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, procedure

I am trying to write a procedure to change the total hours an employee works on projects.

For example, suppose an employee with empno of 012010 is to be assigned 38 hours
per week on all his projects together. Then the parameters to the procedure are
‘012010’ and 38. If the employee currently works 28 hours in total on 5 projects, then
he should be assigned an extra 2 hours on each of the projects. On the other hand, if
he currently works 43 hours on 5 projects, then his hours on each project should be
reduced by 1 hour.

RELEVANT TABLE:

```
DESC Pworks;
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| empno | char(6)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| projno | char(6)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| hours | smallint(6) | YES |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

SELECT * FROM Pworks;
+--------+--------+-------+
| empno | projno | hours |
+--------+--------+-------+
| 000020 | PL2100 |    31 |
| 000030 | IF1000 |    11 |
| 000030 | IF2000 |    10 |
| 000050 | OP1000 |    16 |
| 000050 | OP2000 |    15 |
| 000060 | MA2110 |     8 |
| 000060 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000060 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000060 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000070 | AD3110 |     8 |
| 000070 | AD3111 |     7 |
| 000070 | AD3112 |     7 |
| 000070 | AD3113 |     7 |
| 000090 | OP1010 |    31 |
| 000100 | OP2010 |     8 |
| 000100 | OP2011 |     7 |
| 000100 | OP2012 |     7 |
| 000100 | OP2013 |     7 |
| 000130 | IF1000 |    10 |
| 000130 | IF2000 |    10 |
| 000140 | IF1000 |    10 |
| 000140 | IF2000 |    10 |
| 000150 | MA2110 |     7 |
| 000150 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000150 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000150 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000160 | MA2110 |     7 |
| 000160 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000160 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000160 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000170 | MA2110 |     7 |
| 000170 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000170 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000170 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000180 | MA2110 |     7 |
| 000180 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000180 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000180 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000190 | MA2110 |     7 |
| 000190 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000190 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000190 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000200 | MA2110 |     7 |
| 000200 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000200 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000200 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000210 | MA2110 |     7 |
| 000210 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000210 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000210 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000220 | MA2110 |     7 |
| 000220 | MA2111 |     7 |
| 000220 | MA2112 |     7 |
| 000220 | MA2113 |     7 |
| 000230 | AD3110 |     8 |
| 000230 | AD3111 |     7 |
| 000230 | AD3112 |     7 |
| 000230 | AD3113 |     7 |
| 000240 | AD3110 |     7 |
| 000240 | AD3111 |     7 |
| 000240 | AD3112 |     7 |
| 000240 | AD3113 |     7 |
| 000250 | AD3110 |     7 |
| 000250 | AD3111 |     7 |
| 000250 | AD3112 |     7 |
| 000250 | AD3113 |     7 |
| 000260 | AD3110 |     7 |
| 000260 | AD3111 |     7 |
| 000260 | AD3112 |     7 |
| 000260 | AD3113 |     7 |
| 000270 | AD3110 |     7 |
| 000270 | AD3111 |     7 |
| 000270 | AD3112 |     7 |
| 000270 | AD3113 |     7 |
| 000280 | OP1010 |    31 |
| 000290 | OP1010 |    30 |
| 000300 | OP1010 |    30 |
| 000310 | OP1010 |    30 |
| 000320 | OP2010 |     8 |
| 000320 | OP2011 |     7 |
| 000320 | OP2012 |     7 |
| 000320 | OP2013 |     7 |
| 000330 | OP2010 |     7 |
| 000330 | OP2011 |     7 |
| 000330 | OP2012 |     7 |
| 000330 | OP2013 |     7 |
| 000340 | OP2010 |     7 |
| 000340 | OP2011 |     7 |
| 000340 | OP2012 |     7 |
| 000340 | OP2013 |     7 |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

MY ANSWER:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `change_total_hours`(IN emp_id char(6), IN numhours smallint(6))
COMMENT 'Procedure  to  change  the  total  hours  an  employee  works  on  projects,  taking employee  number and the total  hours as parameter'
BEGIN
   DECLARE total_hours INT(3), num_proj INT(3);
   SELECT SUM(hours), COUNT(*)
   FROM Pworks
   INTO total_hours, num_proj
   WHERE empno = emp_id;

   IF total_hours > hours THEN
      SET @hours = (total_hours - numhours)/num_proj;

   ELSEIF tot_hr_emp < numhours THEN
      SET @hours = (total_hours + numhours)/num_proj;
   END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' num_proj INT(3);
SELECT SUM(hours), COUNT(*)
FROM Pworks
INTO total_ho' at line 4

Comment: Every statement must be terminated, don't give parameters the same name as columns, If DECREASE and INCREASE are comments the should be preceded with  # and I have no idea what decrease_value and increase_value are?

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message, and your debugging attempts?

Comment: @P.Salmon thank you for the help, I think I changed everything but still getting the same error

Comment: Read up on the SET statement.

Comment: There's a lot of details here, but most of them seem to be you copying and pasting your homework assignment, which we're not going to do for you. The body of your "question" doesn't contain any question, any error message, or any output from your current code, and the question in your title doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Your edited question is a lot more concise **but you still haven't included the error message you're getting**. The details in the message may not mean much to you, but *that's why you're asking other people for help*; we can't help you understand things you haven't shown us.

Comment: I included everything and adjusted the question, thank you.